# (Django) Permission denied for deleting a file owned by www-data (of which I'm a member)

Tags: python, django

I have a website built in **Django**, that allows a user to upload a file. This file then gets processed and a bunch of other files are created. These files are owned by the user/group **www-data** of which my account is a member. Someone else wrote the script that creates these files and it uses programs that I am unfortunately not familiar with. These files have rw-r--r-- permissions and I am able to delete them manually as well as through the website.

The website then calls the "*collectstatic*" Django command which copies these files (owned by www-data) to the static_root directory. These files I cannot delete manually, nor can I get the website to call a script to delete them. I get the "**permission denied**" error. Originally these files had the same permssions as the ones they were copied from (rw-r--r--) but I managed to get them to have rw-rw-rw by extending the django StaticFilesStorage object like so:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import StaticFilesStorage
import os

class MyStaticFilesStorage(StaticFilesStorage):        
    def save(self, name, content):
        os.umask(0)
        super(MyStaticFilesStorage, self).save(name, content)
```

I have only just started working with Django and Python this summer so I'm really not that familiar with it. Any help would be appreciated. I don't understand how I can't delete a file that has "write" permission for a group of which I am a member.

---

**Edit:**

Where I think the problem lies: The program that creates the files creates a directory for them that has drwxrwxrwx permission. "*collectstatic*" copies this directory to my static_root directory and the permsissions on that new directory are drwxr-xr-x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a file in a unix-like environemnt you need write permissions on the directory, not on the file itself.

So try to chmod 775 the directory your static files are located in and it should work.

BTW: patching StaticFilesStorage in the way mentioned above is not a good solution imho and shouldn't be required anyway.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply.

_Chmod_ also says 'permission denied', and I don't have access to the _sudo_ command. The original directory that gets created has full rwx permissions, but when the _collectstatic_ command gets called the copy of that directory has drwxr-xr-x permissions. I don't understand why _collectstatic_ is changing the permissions.

And I know my patching of StaticFilesStorage is not the best idea - just getting desperate!

Comment: Calling chmod on the directory worked when I did it from the python script that called 'collectstatic', thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`collectstatic` uses `FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS` and `FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS` (the latter being new in Django 1.7).

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic.